# How to define an area in pixels inside a bigger bounding area GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, clip, random

I am using Google Earth Engine GEE to extract fire information, here I define a bounding box and I clip to that area, but I need to define a random 450x450 pixels area at random inside it to extract only that information.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MCD64A1')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2021-09-01', '2022-01-01'));
var burnedArea = dataset.select('BurnDate');
var img = burnedArea.first();
var burnedAreaVis = {
  min: 30.0,
  max: 341.0,
  palette: ['4e0400', '951003', 'c61503', 'ff1901'],
};

var geometry = 
    /* color: #0b4a8b */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-77.14060933571007, 5.273462776497009],
          [-77.14060933571007, -18.30570331767758],
          [-43.874007773210074, -18.30570331767758],
          [-43.874007773210074, 5.273462776497009]]], null, false);

var clipped = img.clip(geometry);
Map.addLayer(geometry, {}, 'bounding');
 
Map.addLayer(clipped, burnedAreaVis, 'Burned Area');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing so is 'randomly' sampling inside the created geometry, create a buffer (circle) or extracting the bounds (square shape) depending on your preference. Some factors to consider are your pixelSize, as buffer needs an input in meters.

```
var seed = 4321 // change number for different location
var randomPoint = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(geometry, 1, seed)
var pixelSize = 30 // meters
var randomPointBuffer = randomPoint.geometry().buffer(450*pixelSize) // circle
var randomPointBounds = randomPointBuffer.bounds() // squared
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ce6e1ba81d98d79020311afa0b366b34

This will only work for 1 random point. If you want to have more you need to map over each point and then define geometry and bounds inside the function.